# Add parameters in get request inside VisualCode extension

Tags: parameters, visual-studio-code, request, vscode-extensions

I'm creating new VSCode Extension for managing files on server. I have trouble sending get request with required parameters. Is there a way that parameters can be send like code bellow

```
const options =
          {
            url: this.auth_url_base + "api/files/GetFileStructure",
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                  filter: 'null',
                  search : 'null',
                  thumbs : false
              }

          };

        request.get(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
            debugger;
        });
```

Comment: const options =
        {
            url: this.workspaceRoot + "api/files/GetFileStructure",
            method: 'GET',
            qs: {
                filter: null,
                search: null,
                thumbs: false
            }

        };